# Squid Proxy: url_regex acl is not working?

Tags: squid

I am using squid proxy 3.1 in ubuntu machine. I want to allow only urls matching our pattern through our proxy server. I configured acl like below.  Acl for dstdomain is working fine. If i access any url besides `.zmedia.com` , I got proxy connection refused. But the `url_regex` is not working.

What i am trying here is.

Allow only request from **".zmedia.com"**  domain and the request url should be in **"/blog"** context.

```
 #
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 ::1

acl urlwhitelist url_regex -i ^http(s)://([a-zA-Z]+).zmedia.com/blog/.*$
acl allowdomain dstdomain .zmedia.com

acl Safe_ports port 80 8080 8500 7272
# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed 

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl SSL_ports  port 7272        # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !allowdomain
http_access allow urlwhitelist
http_access allow CONNECT SSL_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports


# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
append_domain .zmedia.com

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Please correct me , If i did anything wrong?

Comment: You should check the uri, since url_regex acl doesn't match https connections.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this regexp:

```
^http(s)?://([a-zA-Z]+).zmedia.com/blog/.*$
```

The difference between yours and mine being `?` after `(s)`. This means that `s` in `https` can be present either 0 or 1 times.

Comment: Janne, Thank you for your response. 

I tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with cache_peer_access instead of cache_peer_domain.

1. Create a regex file

`$ vi /my-no-proxy.txt`

Write regex in `/my-no-proxy.txt`

```
^.*my-site-dont-access-with-proxy\.com$
.*you-can-write-any-regex-here.*
```

2. Change `squid.conf`

`vi /etc/squid/squid.conf`

Add below to `squid.conf`

```
cache_peer my-proxy.com parent 8080 0 no-query name=myProxy
acl viaProxy dstdom_regex "/my-no-proxy.txt"
cache_peer_access myProxy deny viaProxy
```